# Not able to access property of object from API fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get certain data from the [Open Weather API](https://openweathermap.org/current) using React and specifically, using hooks. A snippet of my code is as follows:

**App.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeather()
}, [])

const fetchWeather = async () => {

    const dataOneDay = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    )
    const singleDayData = await dataOneDay.json()
    setSingleDayData(singleDayData)
    setIsLoading(false)
    console.log(singleDayData)
}

console.log(isLoading)

return (
    <div className={"weather-container"}>
        <img src={logo} alt={"Logo"} />
        {isLoading === false && <TodayWeather singleDayData={singleDayData} />}
        <h2>{singleDayData.name}</h2>
    </div>
)
```

In the above code, the singleDayData.name property displays as it should (i.e. "London" - see the screenshot below for the full object details),

**TodayWeather.js**

I have another file where I am trying to display the data, where the code to do so is as follows:

```
import React from "react"

const TodayWeather = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={"today-weather"}>
            <h3>Today in {props.name}</h3>
            {console.log("props ", props)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodayWeather
```

The `{console.log("props ", props)}` displays the object in full. However, for some odd reason, the name property is not being displayed.

The object that is returned from the API is the following.

[image: Object from API]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you pass `singleDayData` as a prop to `TodayWeather` you will need to access it through `props.singleDayData.main.temp` Or destruct `singleDayData` from the props object parameter

Also if you just return JSX from your functional component you can omit the return and wrap it in `()`

```
const TodayWeather = ({ singleDayData }) => (
  <div className="today-weather">
    <h3>Today in {singleDayData.name}</h3>
    <span>{singleDayData.main.temp}</span>
  </div>
);
```